# Draw a spiral like an ellipse

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am trying to draw the following diagram in latex:

[image]

I find the following command :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw [domain=0:25.1327,variable=\t,smooth,samples=75]
              plot ({\t r}: {0.002*\t*\t});
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

But it's like a circle.
Can anyone help me?

Comment: Could you please provide with us the equation of that spiral?

Comment: It's phase plane portrait of  differential equations, x'=Ax that A=[matrix 2x2]. for more details please check [the link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phase_plane) @zyy

Comment: @Mohammad Could you please provide with us the equation of that spiral?

Comment: @Andrew This is the formula [formula][1]


  [1]: https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?cht=tx&chl=%5Cfrac%7B%5Cmathrm%7Bd%7Dy%7D%7B%5Cmathrm%7Bd%7Dx%7D%3D%5Cfrac%7B3x-2y%7D%7B5x-2y%7D

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your code shows a circular spiral because you punch in a circular spiral. Try e.g.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw [rotate=-45]
              plot[domain=0:25.1327,variable=\t,smooth,samples=75] ({\t r}: {0.002*\t*\t} and {0.004*\t*\t} );
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

And to add the axes and the arrow, you could use

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw[-stealth] (-3,0) -- (3,0) node[below]{$x$};
        \draw[-stealth] (0,-3) -- (0,3) node[left]{$y$};
        \draw [rotate=-45,postaction=decorate,decoration={markings,
        mark=at position 0.93 with {\arrow{latex}}}]
              plot[domain=0:32,variable=\t,smooth,samples=75] ({\t r}: {0.002*\t*\t} and {0.004*\t*\t} );
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @Mohammad You're welcome!

Answer (score 3):

A PSTricks solution only for comparison and future purposes.

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt,12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-plot}
\begin{document}
\pspicture[algebraic,plotpoints=500](-4,-4)(4,4)
    \rput{-45}(0,0){\psparametricplot[arrows=->]{0}{Pi 15 mul}{t^2*cos(t-Pi/3)/1000|2*t^2*sin(t-Pi/3)/1000}}
\endpspicture
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The quadratic growth is randomly or blindly chosen.